How to schedule irregular local notifications (even if after the app gets killed)
so am building an app that sends about 5 local notifications to the user, at an irregular interval (the timings are internally calculated).
First i tried using Scheduled notifications from the package flutter_local_notification and it works quite smoothly, but from what i found there is no direct way that allows me to schedule all 5 notifications at once on the same channel or maybe like trigger a method when the notification is showed so i can reschedule the next notification.
Then i decided to try and use the WorkManager package and mix it with normal notifications from the flutter_local_notification package so i can call a logic that triggers the next notification time and so on, but am facing couple of problems, first the notification that i schedule using workmanager arent so consistent when i close the app, some times they work as intended, and other times it takes much longer than what it was scheduled, or simply only show when i reopen the app, which can be a bit problematic since i need the notifications to pop up on time.
ideally i would love to find a way to only use the flutter_local_notification package because it works quite smoothly and as intended, but it doesnt seem possible for now.
i think i found a somewhat decent solution, suggested by u/autognome in this post Schedule irregular Notifications combining scheduled notifications by the flutter_local_notification and background_fetch that uses headless function implementation that basically will awaken my app in the background about every 15 minutes, providing a short period of background running-time. which will execute the provided callback fun to reschedule the next notification.
finally if you have dealt with irregularly scheduled local notifications or just have a better solution or advice or would like to point our a mistake that i mentioned please go ahead, as i struggled to find a decent guide to do so and i want this to help people after me (and me) to basically not go through the maze i went through.
Ps: if anyone is having the same problem in the future and want some help, hit me up.

Irregular Notifications in Flutter (Simple Way):

Use flutter_local_notifications.
Schedule silent "check-in" notifications every 15 minutes (wakes the app).
When awake, calculate the next notification time and schedule it using flutter_local_notifications.

This avoids complex background services and offers a good balance for irregular notifications.
In your Flutter code, use the flutter_local_notifications package to schedule a silent notification with a specific ID (e.g., check_in_notification_id). Set the notification's payload to a value that signals it's a check-in (e.g., "payload": "check_in").
Code Example:
// Assuming you have a function to calculate the next notification time
DateTime nextNotificationTime = calculateNextNotificationTime();

// Schedule the silent check-in notification
await FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin().zonedSchedule(
  check_in_notification_id,
  "Silent Check-In",
  "Waking up the app...",
  // Schedule the notification to repeat every 15 minutes
  const PeriodicNotificationRepeat(interval: RepeatInterval.everyFifteenMinutes),
  AndroidNotificationDetails(...), // Set silent notification details
  IOSNotificationDetails(...), // Set silent notification details
  payload: {"payload": "check_in"}, // Payload to identify the check-in
);

Placement of Logic:
You don't necessarily need a specific page. Consider creating a dedicated class or service to handle background notification logic (e.g., BackgroundNotificationService). This service can be registered in your main.dart or appropriate initialization code.

can you ever be so generous and dive a bit deeper into the second point, as in what are silent notifications and by making them trigger every 15 min do you mean by using a periodic notification, and where should i add the logic that schedules the next notification when the app gets reawaken, because i suppose adding the code inside of a random page wont be enough

Silent notifications are like secret messages to your app. They wake it up in the background every 15 minutes (or your chosen time) without bothering the user.

but from what ive seen this will still leave some traces behind (the notification) and i dont want to leave any.
